# How can I create a cold publisher using Reactor-Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, reactive-programming, observer-pattern, project-reactor

Is it possible to create a Kafka publisher without subscribing to it, then, from another application, create a consumer, subscribe to the topic, and trigger the emission of records?

I am creating a publisher by:

1. calling `KafkaSender.create(senderOptions)`
2. followed by `createOutbound()`
3. followed by a succession of calls to `send()` for as long as the application is running.

On the consumer side (a different application), what I do is:

1. call `KafkaReceiver.create(options)`
2. followed by  `receive()`
3. followed by `subscribe(function -> doSomething())`

At the moment, the consumer receives nothing unless I do a `then().subscribe()` on the publisher, which makes it emit straight away. Ideally, I would like it to start emitting when the consumer from the other application subscribes.

Could you please advise me on whether what I am trying to do is feasible?

Many thanks.

The Reactor-Kafka project can be found here: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka

Comment: Would be great to see some small application(s) to let us play from our side.

Comment: Thank you very much for getting back to me. I have created some example applications and shared the code with you on BitBucket. Please note that you will need to edit `reactive-consumer.props` and `reactive-producer.props` in the monitoring project to point to a real Kafka server.

Comment: As it stands, the consumer receives records from a hot producer, but not from a cold one. If you comment out the producer's subscription, the consumer gets nothing. Thanks in advance for helping me out with this!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you should start from the concept *broker*. That is exactly an idea to distinguish the consumer from producer and let the last one to produce and forget and really don't worry if there is a consumer on another side or not.

When the consumer arrives to the broker for subscription, it is able to read all the old records in the topic or just react to a newly produced. But that's already details of the target messaging broker implementation.

There is definitely no API for the consumer to figure out that there are consumers on the topic. I'm afraid you need to implement your own solution. Maybe even via the same Kafka but using a separate topic - something like send/receive command messages and already there, by the appropriate command, understand from the producer side that there is a producer and therefore call  the mentioned `then().subscribe()`.